# How to add spacing between UILabel Words

Tags: ios7, ios6, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I want to increase space between the words of UILabel.
From below code i was able to increase the space between characters but i want to do it for words

```
 NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
[attrStr addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName value:@(4.0) range:NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length)];
```

Any help or pointer will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't think that's possible. But what you could do is to insert "small space characters" between words or it could be more interesting to set a bigger font to spaces. Or you maybe be add this kern attribute only for space

Comment: ok how to set kern attribute for space ?

Comment: Try with initialString = @"ABC DEF", to set the NSKernAttributeName with range NSMakeRange(3,1). Does it works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this tricky method by replacing one space with two space:

```
NSString *str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"  "];
```

Comment: I will accept this answer as i found this as best till now, Dont know this is correct approach but it works   ;)